# If/else statement inside jQuery object array

Tags: jquery, function, object, if-statement

I have this array of objects. I want the value of 'duration' to change based on the width of the screen with an if/else statement.

This is what I've got right now, but I can't get it to work. I think it's because of the variable?

```
($.fn.defaults = {
    items: { start: 0 },
    scroll: {
        easing: "swing",
        duration: function (fztime) {
            var fztime;
            $(window).resize(function() {
                if($(window).width() >= 641) {
                    fztime = 7000;
                } else {
                    fztime = 500;
                }
            }).resize()
        },
        pauseOnHover: !1,
        event: "click",
        queue: !1 }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value from the function, or, rather, set it directly with the ternary operator:

```js
($.fn.defaults = {
  items: {
    start: 0
  },
  scroll: {
    easing: "swing",
    duration: $(window).width() >= 641 ? 7000 : 500
  },
  pauseOnHover: !1,
  event: "click",
  queue: !1
})

console.log($.fn.defaults)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As far as I can make out the function definition within the object seems superfluous. But I don't really know the wider context of your code.